# Why was this answer deleted? Why do answers get deleted without notifying why?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

The answer screenshot below was deleted without saying why.

1. Why delete this answer?
2. Why delete without saying why?

On the face of it, looks like plain abuse of power. Please prove me wrong.

[image]

Comment: I would have answered that question differently, but I agree with both (1) the point you make therein, and that (2) the deletion of your answer is yet another unwarranted action by our recently elected moderators. They should refrain from indulging in so much censorship.

Answer (score 4):

The site has a policy on [deleting answers](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and resources for [writing good answers](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please note that placing words that violate the site's code in another font still violates the [code](https://law.stackexchange.com/conduct). And while we prefer to edit and save valuable content, this answer reflects little effort. For its part, the community chose downvoting and flagging for moderator intervention over editing.

As to question 2: the site doesn't have a text field for deletions. It's possible for moderators to edit flagged posts so they comply with the site's policies. That's what we do in the bulk of cases. Your answer consists of a bolded header that's not responsive to the question and a sentence that's primarily focused on deriding court protocol. If we set aside the snark and squint for a contribution, it'd probably concern literal weight or legal weight. That's a direction you could take a more responsive answer.

Comment: Please feel free to continue your discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113424/discussion-on-answer-by-pat-w-why-was-this-answer-deleted-why-do-answers-get-d).